# VueJS/Javascript: Expected array got object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to vue, trying to display items inside array in the list

**Vue component:**

```html
    <template>
        <div>
           <ul id="array-rendering">
                <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
                    {{ item.message }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        items: {
          type: [],
          default: [
            { message: 'Foo' },
            { message: 'Bar' }
          ]
        },
      },
    }
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    h4{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    </style>
```

Page:

```html
    <ErrorAlert v-bind:items="{result}"/>
```

Here,the `result` is

```json
[
    { message: "Foo2" },
    { message: "Bar2" }
];
```

Instead of getting the values 'foo2' and 'bar2' i am getting the error:`Expected array got object`

Looked at similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422925/nativescript-vue-listview-expected-array-got-object) and tried to parse JSON but still not getting the expected result. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind with `v-bind:items="result"`. Since you wrapped the bound value in `{...}` you made an object literal. Just `"result"` will pass the array.

Answer (score 2):

Vue has a prop which can be of any data type.

Out of all data types, Object, Array should be a function for their default values.

```
export default {
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [
        { message: 'Foo' },
        { message: 'Bar' }
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

And `v-bind:items` can already have javascript variable.
so

```
<ErrorAlert v-bind:items="result"/>
```